# SQL find duplicate records from past 7 days

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates

Hi I am trying to find duplicate webvisits within the past 7 days, I have built a query but it is taking too long to run. Any help in optimizing this query would be much appreciated. I am finding duplicates using the visitorguid.

```
  WITH TooClose
     AS
 (
SELECT
    a.visitid AS BeforeID,
    b.visitID AS AfterID,
    a.omniturecid as [Before om id],
    b.omniturecid as [after om id],
    a.pubid as [Before pub id],
    b.pubid as [after pub id],
    a.VisitorGuid as [Before guid],
    b.VisitorGuid as [after guid],
    a.date as [Before date],
    b.date as [after date]
FROM
    webvisits a
    INNER JOIN WebVisits b ON a.VisitorGuid = b.VisitorGuid
                    AND a.date < b.Date
                    AND DATEDIFF(DAY, a.date, b.date) < 7
 Where a.Date >= '7/1/2015')
 SELECT
*
 FROM
TooClose
  WHERE
BeforeID NOT IN (SELECT AfterID FROM TooClose)
```

Comment: Sample data would be good. Recommend using `SQLFiddle` to do so.

Comment: without knowing what indexes you have, and what your execution plan is, it is hard to offer suggestions.

Comment: Please give examples of what you mean by duplicates.

Comment: I am trying to find duplicate visits based upon the visitorguid and the  attributes of these visits.

Comment: I have a table of webvisit data and what I am trying to do is basically figure out the traffic source of all visits to my site from a user.

Comment: @user5140822 If a user has same VisitorGuid every time they visit your site on same day or different days, then below solution should work for you.

Comment: @NepaliRookie what if i wanted the marketing attributes?

Comment: @NepaliRookie also I want to run this from the 1st of the month and the 7 day lookback to be for each individual day.

Comment: @NepaliRookie your solution rocks though धन्यवाद

Comment: @NepaliRookie the output should be something like this

Comment: @NepaliRookie Date 1 visit, Omniturecid 1, Date 2 visit, Omniturecid 2 and the visitorguid

Comment: I think you may want to provide some sample data in your question. That would be really helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you are trying to find all duplicate webvisits within the past 7 days. Not sure what qualifies as a duplicate webvisit, but here is my attempt to what might work for you:

```
;WITH q1
AS (
    SELECT a.VisitorGuid
          ,a.date
    FROM webvisits a
    WHERE a.DATE >= DATEADD(DAY, -7, cast(getdate() as date))
    )
,q2 AS
    (SELECT q1.VisitorGuid
           ,count(*) as rcount
       FROM q1
      GROUP BY q1.VisitorGuid
     )
SELECT q2.VisitorGuid
FROM q2 
WHERE q2.rcount > 1
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/165f2/1/0)

**UPDATED**

```
;WITH q1
AS (
    SELECT a.VisitorGuid
          ,a.date
          ,a.omniturecid 
    FROM webvisits a
    WHERE a.DATE >= DATEADD(DAY, -7, cast(getdate() as date))
    )
,q2 AS
    (SELECT q1.VisitorGuid
           ,count(*) as rcount
       FROM q1
      GROUP BY q1.VisitorGuid
      HAVING Count(*)> 1
     ) 
SELECT q1.VisitorGuid,
       q1.omniturecid,
       q1.date
  FROM q1
INNER JOIN q2 on q1.VisitorGuid = q2.VisitorGuid
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo2**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/823aa/5/0)

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, it is a good idea to provide sample data. Preferable as an sqlfiddle or as create and insert statements. Here's one approach, I'm to lazy to invent the structure and fill it with data to test with, so it might contain some errors:

```
SELECT ... FROM (
    SELECT VisitorGuid
        ,  date
        , lead(date) over (partition by visitorguid
                           order by date) as next_date
        , omniturecid
        , lead(omniturecid) over (partition by visitorguid
                                  order by date) as next_omniturecid 
        , ...
        , lead(...) ...
    FROM webvisits a
) as x
WHERE DATEDIFF(DAY, date, next_date) < 7
```